# Webpack doesn't bundle changes to some files without restarting server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Can I get some help? I want all the files in my project to automatically trigger a new bundle.js. The files in the modules directory do it. But files in partials directory don't.

The file structure is shown below in image file.

[These are my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWsjd.png)

Changes to files Home.js trigger a new bundle. But changes to Main.js doesn't without a server restart. Home.js is a dependency of Main.js

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'  
import Home from '../Home.js'
export default class Main extends Component{  
  render(){  
    return(  
      '<'Home/'>' 
    )
  }
}
```

**Webpack config:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
devServer: {     
  port: 8080 
},   
entry: './index.js', 
output: {
  path: 'public',
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/'   
}, 
plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()   ] : [],
module: {
  loaders: [
   { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'file' },
   { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' }, 
   { test: /\.css/, loaders: ['style', 'css'],
   include: __dirname + '/public' }
 ]   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add [resolving](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html) function which is necessary to use `import` and `require` references in your code. And I think you have some syntax mistakes in your loaders. Replace those two things and it will work I think.

> Resolve is used to find “import” and “require” references that are not
>   immediately available in the current path. For example: how a call to
>   require(“../homepage”) might be translated to (“../homepage/index.js”)
>   or how a import react from ‘react’ might be interpreted if your
>   node_modules folder is named something else.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

**Loaders:**

```
{
   test: /\.js[x]?$/,
   loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'],
   exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
}
```

**Applied to your config:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: 8080
    },
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: 'public',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: TARGET === 'production' ? [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()] : [],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'file'},
            {
                test: /\.js[x]?$/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'],
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css/, loaders: ['style', 'css'],
                include: __dirname + '/public'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I made those changes and am not getting any improvement. Any other ideas?

Comment: I am getting errors : 'process' and '__dirname' not defined. Not sure if that means anything. Everything in the components directory is working. Components is a directory in the root directory. Files in the partials directory which is in the components directory don't get bundled unless I restart webpack. ???

Comment: Add `const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;` and after that add instead of `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `TARGET`

Comment: That didn't change anything. The problem is that files 2 levels down are not being watched by webpack. Files in a directory within the root are being watched, and changes to files in that directory trigger webpack to rebundle the site. But files in a directory within that directory are not being watched, This second directory one level down is out of the loop somehow.